# how to compute this formula without using for loop

Tags: matlab

I would like to compute the correlation between two groups of data without using `for-loop`. With loop, the following code is the solution.

```
clear all
clc
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
y = [7 6 5 4 3 2 1];
sum = 0;
for i = 1:length(x)
    sum = sum + (x(i)-mean(x))*(y(i)-mean(y));
end
p = sum/(length(x)-1)
```

Comment: If you look closely, you can see for yourself you are performing elementwise multiplicatons with the same iterator, if that gives you some hint.

Comment: @Divakar, you mean `sum( (x-mean(x)).*(y-mean(y)))/(length(x)-1)`, it did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Well done! Feels good I bet figuring out for yourself!

Comment: @CroCo, note that you can answer your own question... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it as follows

```
clear all
clc
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
y = [7 6 5 4 3 2 1];
p = sum( (x-mean(x)).*(y-mean(y)))/(length(x)-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like covariance to me.  Make those row vectors column vectors, then take either element of the minor diagonal cov(x,y) and you should have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
sum = 0;
for i = 1:length(x)
    sum = sum + (x(i)-mean(x))*(y(i)-mean(y));
end
p = sum/(length(x)-1)
```

with

```
p = sum( ( x-mean(x) ) .* ( y-mean(y) ) )/(length(x)-1)
```

EDIT: Whoops, should have read comments.